# How would I sort columns based on other columns that are base on other columns in Google Sheets

Tags: new-operator

I am  TA for an enganering class and the students are building mouse trap cars. They are scored for 4 diffrent events. The teatcher has a spreadsheet, but it requires a lot of manual work. I was trying to automate the workflow so he only has to change the value of each test.
What I am trying to get is if I would change a test vale, the sheet would

a. sort the value within the test
b. move the students names with there value
c. add there scores from all the test
d. sort there total score with there name

[exsample sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzEry.png)

I have tried some other "codes" i found on google.
I could not interprie what the explanations where for the "codes".